# Continuous Audio Playback despite Orientation Change

Tags: android, audio

This question has been asked a few times, but none of the answers have helped me solve my problem so I'm posting my version of it.

I'm creating an app that plays a list of songs through a service.  The problem is that I got a null exception error from the mediaPlayer after I rotate the device.  As you can see below, I first start and then bind to my service in the onResume method.  Likewise, I unbind and stop the service in the onDestroy method.

---

```
protected void onResume() {
    if (playIntent == null) {
        playIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MediaService.class);

 //       if (n < 0) {
            startService(playIntent);
            bindService(playIntent, mediaConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            Log.d("Check", "Started Service");
  //      }
    }

    super.onResume();
}
```

---

In my service, I set up the mediaPlayer in the service's onCreate method as below.  I have a few things in the onStartCommand method (like creating a notification to show in the action bar). I also return Start_sticky in onStartCommand method.

Unfortunately, like I said, when I rotate the device, I get a null exception from the mediaPlayer.

Please help; I've been trying to fix this for days.

---

```
static private MediaPlayer player;
private final IBinder musicBind = new MediaBinder();
Notification notification;
private int playbackDuration;
static Uri paths[][] = new Uri[MainActivity.NUMBER_OF_ARTISTS][MainActivity.NUMBER_OF_TRACKS];

public void onCreate() {
    // create the service
    super.onCreate();
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.reset();
    player.setLooping(true);
    initMediaPlayer();

    Log.d("Check", "In Service's OnCreate method");
```

---

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace. Also, if the whole point of running a Service is that it will continue beyond the lifecycle of the Activity, why are you stopping the service when the Activity is destroyed?

Comment: When you rotate your screen, the activity get's destroyed, which in case you are stopping your service in onDetroy stops the service also. Try not killing the service in onDestroy

Comment: Ohhhhh....I didn't onDestory was called when you rotated the screen...wow....Thanks, let me try that then.  But then how can I end the service if I want to end the application completely because isn't onDestroy called then as well?

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much!  Only problem now is that the notification doesn't go away...

Comment: I have a new problem now.  I removed the unbind() bit from the onDestroy method, but now I get a null pointer exception from the mediaPlayer when I try to control it.  My service has an onStartCommand method where I return Service.Start_Sticky, but still no good.  Help??